# Expectation of cumulative density function

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with cumulative density function $F$ (say the distribution is continuous). I want to know whether
$$ E [F(X+y))] = F(y)$$
holds or, if $f$ is the density function $$ E[ f(X+y) ] = f(y)$$ holds.